# How to interpret the comma in this sentece?

Tags: grammar, meaning

This is a line of Ghost in the Shell´s dialogue:

> より存在する為に複雑、多様化しつつ時にはそれを捨てる。

how it is interpreted the comma with "複雑"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「複雑{ふくざつ}、多様化{たようか}しつつ」

is to avoid the wordiness and redundancy of

> 「複雑**化**、(かつ/および) 多様**化**しつつ」